# What is a gksrnrdj Word?

Tags: cipher, word-property, language, computer-puzzle

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a gksrnrdj Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

Font does not matter but case does.

The CSV version:

```
gksrnrdj Words™,Not gksrnrdj Words™
go,stop
query,word
Rich,poor
Queen,king
fort,castle
slacks,shirt
victor,foxtrot
thorns,thank
fortytwo,eightyfour
virgo,scorpio
England,Monaco
sudan,Sudan
TPR,RPQ
```

---

Find the pattern.

> Read the tags.

Bonus question 1:

> Are there any longer "gksrnrdj Words"? If so, what is the longest such word in Scrabble?

Bonus question 2:

> Write a computer program to determine if a word is a "gksrnrdj Word".

Hint 1:

> Try using Google Translate.

Hint 2:

> Font does not matter but case does.

Hint 3:

> You have probably noticed that every "gksrnrdj Word" starts off on the left side of the Qwerty keyboard. Of course this is not a coincidence, but this fact doesn't seem to help much.

Hint 4:

> "gksrnrdj Words" can not contain any capital letters except E, O, P, Q, R, T and W. More specifically, O and P cannot appear at the beginning of a "gksrnrdj Word", while E, Q and W cannot appear at the end of a "gksrnrdj Word".

Hint 5:

> Where was the last Winter Olympiad held?
>  <sub>*This hint is now outdated. Please read the post date.</sub>

Hint 6:

> No 1-letter gksrnrdj Words exist. There are approximately 266 2-letter gksrnrdj Words and approximately 4389 3-letter gksrnrdj Words in total, if non-dictionary words are also counted.

Comment: Only spelling is relevant. Pronunciation and meaning are not. Also, Hint 5 will go outdated in about a week. By the way, please correct mistakes, if any.

Comment: Hint 5 has gone outdated.

Answer (score 4):

### Partial Answer?

---

**Figuring out the rule:**

> Based on hint number 5 (written before the [2022 Winter Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Winter_Olympics)), we can assume that this has to do with Korea. (The [2018 Winter Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Winter_Olympics) were in Pyeongchang, South Korea)
> Also based on the fact that capitalization matters but not font, this has to do with the Korean [Hangul keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_language_and_computers). This keyboard layout has the QWERTY keys QWERTOP (mentioned in Hint #4) as the only ones that can be changed by using the Shift key ("capitalized").
> Using this QWERTY-based layout and translating "gksrnrdj" into Korean, we get 한국어 (hangug-eo), which translates to "Korean". Google Translate has a built-in keyboard for most languages, and thats what I used.
> The translated gksrnrdj Words give the following list:

**List of Words**

> go - 해 sun
> query - 볃교 school
> Rich - 꺄초 cacho
> Queen - 뼏두 whole
> fort - 랛 left
> slacks - 님찬 Nimchan
> victor - 퍄챗ㄱ 
> thorns - 쇄군 runaway
> fortytwo - 랙숏재 rack shot material
> virgo - 퍅해 
> England - 뚜히ㅑ노 Absolutely no
> sudan - 녕무 bye bye
> TPR - 쎾 ㎾

**The Rule(?)**

> A word is a gksrnrdj Word™ when it can be typed in Korean using a hangul keyboard and it translates into an English word? I feel like there is some other element I'm missing due to quite a few of the translations being quite weird or not even English.

Comment: Did you intend to not put the first section of the answer in spoilers? If you didn't, I put in a suggested edit that puts it in spoilers.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks WoomyRogue for doing the bulk of the work in your partial answer: [What is a gksrnrdj Word?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114645/what-is-a-gksrnrdj-word/114648#114648). Allow me to top it off.

A gksrnrdj Word™ is

> A sequence of characters that, when entered on a [Dubeolsik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Dubeolsik) keyboard, yields a sequence of *complex* [Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul) characters.

> A *complex* Hangul character is made from combining the elementary Hangul characters, called *jamos*. For example, entering `g` and `o` alone gives the jamos, `ㅎ` and `ㅐ`, respectively, but entering them together combines them into the single character, `해`. On the contrary, typing `sun` gives `녀ㅜ`, where the `ㅜ` from the `n` does not combine. Therefore, `go` is a gksrnrdj Word™ and `sun` is not.

The reason they are called gksrnrdj Word™s is because

> Entering `gksrnrdj` translates to `Korean`, as pointed out by WoomyRogue.

The following Python script classifies words as gksrnrdj Word™s or not:

> ```
> # https://github.com/kjh618/dubeolsik-automata
> from dubeolsik_automata import join_jamos, qwerty_to_dubeolsik
>
> def is_gksrnrdj(word):
>     try:
>         jamos = qwerty_to_dubeolsik(word)
>     except KeyError:
>         return False
>
>     word = join_jamos(jamos)
>     jamos = set(jamos)
>
>     for letter in word:
>         if letter in jamos:
>             return False
>
>     return True
> ```